# How to find a value from an expression

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep, find

I have below expression from which I would like to output +m= value

```
"ginger bread.k +log ../output1 -format +m=3 0 +sleep 10 +suspend 10"
```

The output value should be "3"

Any suggestions?

Comment: `echo 3` would work, too. I think it'd be useful to describe which lines/fields are variable and what the possible "3" values are, so that you end up with a flexible & correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "ginger bread.k +log ../output1 -format +m=3 0 +sleep 10 +suspend 10" | ...
```

Replace `...` by :

[grep](/questions/tagged/grep) :

```
grep -oP '\+m=\K\d+'
```

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
sed -E 's/.*\+m=([0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
 awk -F'+m=| ' '{print $7}'
```

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -lne 'print $& if /\+m=\K\d+/'
```

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
x="ginger bread.k +log ../output1 -format +m=3 0 +sleep 10 +suspend 10"
[[ $x =~ \+m=([0-9]+) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

#### Output

```
3
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer Gilles. grep and sed options works in my script. For some reason, I am not getting any output

Comment: All of these commands are tested successfully in a linux console

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer Gilles. I am interested in grep and sed options. For some reason, I am not getting any output with grep option. I got the correct output with sed option. If I have number such as 12, it is giving only 1 as output. So I updated it to "sed -r 's/.*\+m=([0-9][0-9]).*/\1/'". This gave me 12 as output. However, if the input is +m=4, i am getting 44 as output.

Comment: grep need -P support, and I edited sed command to me more portable. Wich flavor of unix do you use ?

Comment: Gilles, `\+` is a GNU-ism.  But using `-E` is portable between GNU and BSD `sed` and will also be specified in the next edition of POSIX.

Comment: POST edited accordingly

Comment: Gilles, I missed your updated code for sed. "sed -E 's/.*\+m=([0-9]+).*/\1/'" This works for all cases. For grep command, it might be something to do with my UNIX. I ma using RH5.8 machine. Thank you for your help